Connecting a sata ssd drive to my sas hotswap bay
I purchased the SilverStone Technology RM21-304 2U Micro-ATX Rackmount Server Chassis with Four 3.5" hot-swap Bays, SST-RM21-304.  The description says "Supports four 2.5"/3.5" Sas/SATA HDD/SSD".  Here is the specification of the HDD backplane "4 ports SAS / SATA to Mini-SAS SFF-8087 x 1"
Along with an Internal Mini SAS to SATA Cable, I connected all four cables to the SATA plugs on my motherboard and the SAS connector to the server's backplane. I only plugged in one of my SATA SSD drives, and the lights are on when I turn the computer on. But I can't see the drive when I do an lsblk command or on the bios.
I took a picture of the connector in the hot-swap bay

Am I missing something?  I tried to do some research on the chassis but couldn't find anything.  Am I missing or misunderstanding something?  Any help would be much appreciated.
